# How to pass value to initWithCoder of second view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using pushViewController method. i want to check some condition in initWithCoder method in second view controller, but as I use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` in first controller `initWithCoder` is called before setting property of second view controller. So how can I check that condition?

Comment: I am a bit confused. So I need to make a quick review before answering. Is the only problem XCode calling initWithCoder in the SecondViewController before you set the property in the FirstViewController?

Comment: You can't set a property on the second view controller before calling `initWithCoder` because the object *doesn't exist* before it is initialised. `viewDidLoad` is your first real opportunity to do things conditionally.

Comment: ASNPhoto *chatViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoStoryBoard"];
    chatViewController.isFromProfile=YES;       as i create instance of ASNPhoto initwithcoder method called. i want to use isFormProfile property for check

Comment: Okay so you dont want to call initWithCoder before you set the property, right?

Comment: @Paulw11 i know that but i must check in initWithCoder method how to set this property during object initialization?

Comment: You can't. You simply don't have access to the object before it is initialised.

Comment: Haha funny, seems like you don't care me but got the answer. Use NSNotificationCenter. Don't wait from me any explanation

Comment: You could also use a singleton but it is a horrible design pattern. Much better to configure appropriately in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: Or you could set something in `NSUserDefaults`.  Or you could use an actual MVC structure and make the condition part of the shared Model.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right it worked. you are great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we create instance of viewcontroller at that time initwithCoder method is called. so
i used singleton class boolean variable set in prepareforsegue method and used in initWithCoder Method it works for me.